# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: editMaterial

Tags: jquery, laravel

I tried to move some functions in to a file to get a better order. If the function is inside the laravel blade, it works well. but if i move it into the file editOp.js there is the following error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: editMaterial

Call function:

```
        <td class="text-right">
        <a onclick="editMaterial('{{$opMaterial->id}}')" class="btn btn-link text-info" ><i class="fa fa-pencil " aria-hidden="true"> </i> </a>
        <a onclick="deleteMaterialItem('{{$opMaterial->id}}')" class="btn btn-link text-danger" ><i class="fa fa-times " aria-hidden="true"> </i> </a>
    </td>
```

Include js:

```
@endsection
@section('footer_scripts')
<script>
    var opId = '{{$op->id}}'
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('/assets/plugins/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js') }}" ></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/opMaterial.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/editOp.js') }}" ></script>
```

editOp.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function editMaterial(id) {
    $('#editMaterial-' + id).hide();
    $('#saveMaterial-' + id).show();
    $('#materialRow-' + id).hide();
    $('#materialFormRow-' + id).show();
    $("#materialFormRow-" + id + " input:text").first().focus();
}

function saveMaterial(id) {
    $('#editMaterial-' + id).show();
    $('#saveMaterial-' + id).hide();
    $('#materialRow-' + id).show();
    $('#materialFormRow-' + id).hide();
    saveMaterialFormRow(id);
}

function cancelMaterial(id) {
    $('#editMaterial-' + id).show();
    $('#saveMaterial-' + id).hide();
    $('#materialRow-' + id).show();
    $('#materialFormRow-' + id).hide();
}

})
```

Unfortunately, google was not helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
<a onclick="editMaterial('{{$opMaterial->id}}')" class="btn btn-link text-info" ><i class="fa fa-pencil " aria-hidden="true"> </i> </a>
<a onclick="deleteMaterialItem('{{$opMaterial->id}}')" class="btn btn-link text-danger" ><i class="fa fa-times " aria-hidden="true"> </i> </a>
```

The `onclick` attributes expect global functions. But your functions are defined within the `$(document).ready(function() {` function, so they aren't global.

**Solution:** Remove the `$(document).ready(function() {`  part and let your functions be global.

Alternative, probably better, solution: don't use `onclick` and bind the functions to the click event using `$('selector').click(function (){})`. This could (should) be done within the  `$(document).ready(function() {`  function.